# Removing prompt for parameter on subform when added to navigation form in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am creating a database with interface to keep track of student data for a school.

The particular issue I am having is on a form which modifies student data, specifically a sub form which shows classes which the student has been assigned to. The form (with sub-form) is shown below (red arrow indicates the sub-form):

[image: modify student with sub-form]

The sub-form gets its data from a query which uses a parameter from the main form (the MIS_ID field). The query is below:

```
SELECT classes.classCode, subjects.subjectCode
FROM (subjects INNER JOIN classes ON subjects.[subjectID] = classes.[subjectID]) 
INNER JOIN studentClasses ON classes.[classID] = studentClasses.[classID]
WHERE (((studentClasses.MIS_ID)=[Forms]![modifyStudent]![MIS_ID]));
```

This all works fine, until I add this form to a navigation form tab. Once I do this, when I try to open the navigation form, I get the following prompt:

[image: prompt for parameter]

This prompt does not appear when I just open the main Modify Student form. Also, strangely enough, if I open the Modify Student form first, and then open the Navigation form - the prompt does not appear.

How can I prevent Access from displaying this prompt. My MS access skills are not fantastic, so simple explanations would help.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the query changes always? if not why don't you make it as a standard query without where clause, bind the master and sub forms via
LinkMasterField, LinkChildField..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to answer your question "Why this is not working in Navigation-form"
navigation control has a "navigationsubform" control where your forms will be loaded. this means your master form (modifyStudent) is loaded into the "NavigationSubform" form control hence the original form name (ModifyStudent) is not reachable.

to access the parent value from your sub-form you could either use

```
 me.parent!field.value
```

or

```
NavigationForm.NavigationSubform.field.value
```

**alternatively** just bind the master and child forms using linkMasterFiled and linkChildField.

**OR**
if you really want to construct the SQL:
do in in the sub-form_onOpen event and assign it to the me.recordSource
this way you can access `me.Parent.Field.value`

Comment: Thanks for this! For first response - binding the master and child forms - fixed my specific issue.

Your second response, placing the SQL into the form_open event, helped me with a subsequent issue.